# Create Custom Button in Lightning that calls an Apex Class Method

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, custom-button, lightning-experience, lightning-button

I am new to Lightning and I would like to create a Custom Button (or maybe an Action) that just calls a Method in an Apex Class  (in which I am sending some parameters).

Is this posible to do?

Cheers.

Comment: Hi i@jmarco, I would recommend you follow [Trailheads](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/) in order to get familair with creating lightning components - amongst other things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create a lightning component that implements force:lightningQuickAction. After this you will be able to override your Action using this lightning component.
You can program your client side controller to set a callback function, that would call your Apex class to perform some logical calculation.
This is fairly simple and you can find numerous example on trailhead.

Edited: This code will rest in your JS controller:

```
var action = cmp.get("c.YourMethodName");
action.setParams({
     param1: cmp.get("v.something1"),
     param2: cmp.get("v.something2")
});
action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
   if (response.state === "SUCCESS"){
       var serverResponse = response.getReturnValue();
   }    
});
$A.enqueueAction(action);
```

Check out this link: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/lex_dev_lc_basics/units/lex_dev_lc_basics_server

Comment: Thanks for the response, but how can I pass  and receive the parameter to the lightning component?

Comment: Have edited my answer

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! But my problem is that once I have the parameters on the component, I know how to send to the controller side, but how can I pass the parameters from the origin page to the component (For example I am on one determinate Opportunity, how can I send the Id of the oportunity to the component?)

Comment: When you override your Action button using the lightning component, lightning automatically adds an aura attribute called recordId. However, you need to add force:hasRecordId interface in the component. See this link https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_interfaces_force_hasrecordid.htm